# How to get the grid (building baseline)information when importing from IFC file to forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I converted an IFC file containing grid (building baseline) information(represented as IFCGRID and IFCGRIDAXIS), to SVF2 and imported it into Forge Viewer by referring to the following link.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api

However, the AECModelData was null and I could not find the grids label and coordinates.
It was represented as a white line in the 3DViewer, but there was no property to label the coordinates.
Is there a way to get the coordinates and label of the grid (building baseline) when  importing from IFC file to forge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because the "AEC model data" extraction is currently only available for Revit models, not IFC. You could try linking the IFC file into a Revit document, and then convert the Revit file instead, but I'm not sure if that would help.

Let me reach out to the engineering team and find out if this (generating the AEC data for IFC files is on the roadmap).

Comment: Ok, so for now there is no plan to support the AEC Model Data extraction for IFC designs. So if you need to extract additional information from your IFC files, you would have to use one of the external toolkits such as http://ifcopenshell.org.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's a shame that Forge can't extract the IFC information, but I will try an external toolkit.

Comment: I'd suggest that you keep an eye on the Model Derivative service [changelog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/change_history/changelog). If there's sufficient demand, I think the feature could be considered in the future.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks for the additional information, I like Forge because it keeps adding new features and I hope it will become more and more compatible with IFC.